# Django Evolution: How do I add a new field at a specific position?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-evolution

Is there a way to tell Django Evolution to add a new field to a database table at a specific position, similar to the AFTER statement of (My)SQL?
I have a table with some columns and I want to add new_column after column1. Using SQL directly I would do this:

```
ALTER TABLE  `db_table` ADD  `new_column` DATETIME NULL DEFAULT NULL AFTER  `column1`
```

For Django Evolution this translates to:

```
MUTATIONS = [
    AddField('DbTable', 'new_column', models.DateTimeField, null=True, ...)
]
```

However, this would add new_column to the *end* of the table, is there something I can pass in for the dots in the above statement giving more control over the order?

Answer (score 1):

Django does not depend or care about the column position in the database. My guess is that Django Evolution works the same way.

So you shouldn't depend or care too much about database internals either, in the end that is why you are using the ORM, right?

If you really have to do it, I suggest subclassing `django_evolution.mutations.AddField` and overwriting the `add_column` method to integrate the `AFTER` statement in the list of SQL statements this method returns. There might be better places, this would be a hack.

Comment: There are lots of cases where you care a quite lot about the database underneith your ORM.

Comment: But the order of columns in a table?